# show a div in html using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on a simple project what I want to know that when I click on login button I want some thing like this
[image]

and when i click any where except a div the div should be disappear
can some one tell me how can I do something like that?
sorry for my bad English i hope that i make my problem clear

```
<htm>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
          <div> </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: @Spokey thanx that what im really looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it using `CSS`.

Add a class to you div

```
<div class="someDiv"></div>
```

CSS

```
.someDiv{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    z-index:1000;
    background:yellow;
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-150px; 
    margin-left:-150px; 
    display:none;
}
```

Jquery: to show

```
$(".someDiv").show()
```

on click of login button

```
$("#login").click(function () {
     $(".someDiv").show();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9umYd/ and http://jsfiddle.net/9umYd/1/

Comment: You should also make sure to set the `z-index` high so that it doesn't get overlapped by other elements.

Answer (score 0):

The following code attaches a listener to the login button and once clicked will show the popup, the second part attaches a listener on the document and checks if the click was on the popup div or not

```
$('yourloginbutton').on('click', function(){
 $('#popup').show();
});
$(document).on('click', function(event){
 if(event.target.id != "popup"){
 $('#popup').hide();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo:  [http://jsfiddle.net/steven10172/u5E8z/](http://jsfiddle.net/steven10172/u5E8z/2/)

CSS to center perfectly in the page:

```
.someDiv{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    background: yellow;
    display: none;
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

JavaScript to show:

```
$(".someDiv").show()
```

HTML:

```
<div class="someDiv">
    Above
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    Below
</div>
```